# VBA - Find exact match of a name in a string

Tags: excel, vba, string

I'm trying to create this tool that will, by looking through a list of expenses, be able to calculate the amount owed to each employee. So from our account software I can export an excel document with 2 columns. The first column have the amount and the second will have the following strings:

"Lunch, outlay Tanne"

"Train ticket, outlay Anne"

"Lunch, outlay Dennis"

"Lunch, outlay Anne"

The excel document will then look through all the expenses and calculate the total amount owed to each person. So far I've used the following code to calculate the total amounts (some of the variables are calculated earlier, this is just the part calculating the total amount):

```
'Calcualte total amount
   For i = 1 To NamesTotal
       TotalAmount = 0
       NameString = UCase(Cells(i + 1, 7))
       For j = 1 To EntriesTotal
           CellText = UCase(Cells(j + 2, 3))
               If InStr(1, CellText, NameString) Then
                   Amount = Cells(j + 2, 4)
                   TotalAmount = TotalAmount + Amount         
               End If
           End If
       Next

       Cells(TableStart + i, 3) = Cells(i + 1, 7)
       Cells(TableStart + i, 4) = TotalAmount
       Cells(TableStart + i, 4).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
    Next
```

The list of names is listed in column 7, the strings in column 3 and amount in column 4. The list works fine (I have a little more code) but the problem lies with names very similar to each other

```
If InStr(1, CellText, NameString) Then
```

In my example above the name "Anne" is part of the name "Tanne" so the list for Tanne will include the expenses for Anne as well. So how do I change the code so that it will find the exact match?

Comment: InStr(1, CellText, NameString) you will get the position of NameString in CellText. i think your if statement mentioned above does not check for a condition.Try to use Excel consolidate or you can create an if statement checkinig if NameString =CellText

Comment: Can't you adapt your account software to give you three columns, and remove the word "Outlay"?

Answer (score 1):

You could write a regex function that looks for the name as a word using word boundary syntax i.e. \bName\b

In my example the arguments to the function equate to `CellText, NameString`

Try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/9TQ35f/1).

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TEST()
    Dim rng As Range
    For Each rng In [A1:A4]
       If IsNamePresent(rng.Value, "Anne") Then
           'do something
       End If
    Next
End Sub

Public Function IsNamePresent(ByVal inputString As String, testName As String)
    IsNamePresent = False
    With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False '<== You may want to change this
        .Pattern = "\b" & testName & "\b"
        If .TEST(inputString) Then IsNamePresent = True
    End With
End Function
```

Test values:

[image]

---

Regex:

\bAnne\b
/
gm

`\b` assert position at a word boundary `(^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)`

`Anne` matches the characters `Anne` literally (case sensitive)

`\b` assert position at a word boundary `(^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)`.

So, must be `Anne`  as a word and not `Anne` as part of a longer string.

Comment: Just a doubt. Isn't `name` a reserved word for VBA than may cause conflict when executing code? I mean, wouldn't be better maybe something like `vName as String` and `.Pattern = "\b" & vName & "\b"` just in case? Just asking, your code looks good for me :)

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns  Oopsy... I meant to change that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

one of the possible solutions (the way to achieve required result):

```
Function getval(searchStr As String, rng As Range) As String
    Dim dic As Object: Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim cl As Range, wrd
    For Each cl In rng
        For Each wrd In Split(Replace(cl.Value2, ",", ""))
            If LCase(wrd) = LCase(searchStr) Then dic.Add cl.Value2, ""
    Next wrd, cl
    getval = Join(dic.keys, vbNewLine)
End Function
```

**test**[image]